# Notifications in Android don't work

Tags: android, notifications

i'm trying to show notifications sent by my app, but they don't work. In my app, given a condition, the notification must be shown. This is the method I'm using.

```
public void showNotification(){

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificacion = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MapsScreen.this);
    notificacion.setTicker("Bicis cerca")
            .setContentTitle("Bicis cerca")
            .setContentText("Bicis a menos de " + ProfileScreen.getDistance())
            .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.app.sb" + R.raw.bike));

    PendingIntent myPendingIntent;
    Intent myIntent = new Intent();
    Context myContext = getApplicationContext();

    myIntent.setClass(myContext, MapsScreen.class);
    myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(myContext, 0, myIntent, 0);
    notificacion.setContentIntent(myPendingIntent);

    Notification n = notificacion.build();

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(1,n);

    Log.d("Status", ": entrando");
}
```

This method is called after the condition is triggered, and the mehtod works because it writes on the log.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a compulsory argument.

`setSmallIcon`, `setContentTitle`, `setContentMessage` are compulsory.

Add `setSmallIcon` to your `NotificationBuilder` and it should work.

Reference: [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Required)